# Counting number of running processes with WMI python is slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, wmi

I'm testing a 'simple' python program I made for some computer checks. 
I'm using the wmi module to retrieve the information. However, a simple count thread for counting running processes takes about 12 to 13 seconds. The number of running processes is around 300

I wonder if I'm missing something, since I'm a bit surprised how slow this run.

- OS: Windows 10 enterprise
- Python: 3.8.2 32bit
- wmi: 1.5.1
- wxpython: 4.1.0

When a button is pressed several threads are launched, but most of them give back the data instantly, but these don't loop through e.g. the process list.

to start the thread I use:

```
newObject = countProcess()
newObject.start()
```

The class (thread) looks like:

```
class countProcess(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        my_object = dict(status='Running', result='')        
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'testListener', message=2,arg2=my_object)
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        d = wmi.WMI(find_classes=False)
        count = 0
        for process in d.Win32_Process():
            count +=1
        my_object = dict(status='idle', result=count)        
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'testListener', message=2,arg2=my_object)
        #print (count)
        del d
```

Am I doing something wrong or is looping through wmi processes just slow and I have to accept this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way to speed things up A LOT...
by selecting with only one field name, it's now only 4 seconds instead of 12 to 13!

changing:

```
for process in d.Win32_Process():
```

to

```
for process in d.Win32_Process(["Name"]):
```

did the trick! 
I had no idea that this would make such an impact. 
Anymore ideas to further speed things up are welcome!